# Unable to access Spark table with decimal type column from Azure Synapse SQL pool

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have a spark dataframe with one column that is in decimal type.
Whenever I try to save the table into database using overwrite method it just doesn't write. But I don't get any error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = ['15860461.48']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, StringType())

df.show(truncate=False)

df2 = df.withColumn('value', col('value').cast('decimal(19, 4)'))
#df2 = df.withColumn('value', col('value').cast(DoubleType()))
df2.show(truncate=False)

df2.printSchema()

#spark.sql("DROP TABLE DBNAME.TABLENAME)
df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("DBNAME.TABLENAME")
```

I even tried dropping table before overwriting. Still it doesn't work.

It only works if I use `DoubleType()` instead of `DecimalTyple()`.

I run everything in `Azure Synapse`. Spark version `2.4.2`

Comment: Run this and check if you are getting any error, for decimal type--->spark.table(''DBNAME.TABLENAME").show()

Comment: I am not getting an error for this. I get error when I do SQL query on the table (not from spark)

Comment: So you are getting output when you try to access from spark. Are you accessing that table from sql pool?

Comment: Yes I am. This works if I use doubletype and If I use decimaltype, the SQL fails

Comment: Could you please update these info in your question and also paste the error?

Comment: It basically says not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236296/discussion-between-mohana-b-c-and-vj-d).